# Python-Fanuc write Parameter Variable pyfanuc

Tags: python

I'm trying to write data from a cnc fanuc with pyfanuc (https://github.com/diohpix/pyfanuc) library in python, but in this file there is no write data macro function i want to write but my code note working.

def writemacro(self, macro_num, values):
"""
Write values to a macro variable.

```
    Parameters:
    - macro_num: The macro variable number.
    - values: List of values to write to the macro variable.

    Returns:
    - Length of the response if successful, None otherwise.

    """

    cmd = pack(">HHH", 1, 1, 0x16)  # Command to write macro variable
    print(cmd)

    value_str = ''.join([str(value) + ',' for value in values])[:-1]  # Convert values to a comma-separated string
    data = pack(">H", macro_num) + pack(">i", len(value_str)) + value_str.encode()

    payload = cmd + data
    self.sock.sendall(self._encap(pyfanuc.FTYPE_VAR_REQU, payload))
    response = self._decap(self.sock.recv(1500))
    return response["len"] if response["len"] == 0 else None
```